# Codeigniter PDF displays in unreadable format

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

In the below codeigniter i have placed the controller.Now i have placed a PDF file in a view and i want to call the PDF file from the controller.but it displays like unreadable format (ie)

`ÄQ°ùÂ/B‘]xJxyEÆ›Vòþ˜X‚X ð?¼—ä*î7îç·JÚ–ÎÐhK*_ÝüÊ®ˆ¯=»W'{(`.

Controller:

```
<?php

class Help extends ci_controller
{   
    function index(){
        $this->load->helper(array('My_Pdf')); 
        $this->load->view('ss.pdf');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a redirect to your PDF file:

```
public function index() {
    redirect("test.pdf");
}
```

Or load the PDF file in the controller, making sure you set the correct header required to read the PDF file:

```
public function index() {
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        include("test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: It shows The page you requested was not found.But i place the PDF file in my view.My aim to load the PDF File from controller.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Make sure you are referencing the file correctly, check where your index.php file is located and go from there.

Comment: It Shows The page you requested was not found. In controller i have placed the code you provide in controller  and in view i place test.pdf.    http://localhost/seatingreport4/index.php/help/test.pdf

Comment: If I'm looking at this correctly, you should do your include like so: include("help/ss.pdf");

Comment: In this url http://localhost/seatingreport4/index.php/help    the PDF is displaying in Black and in this url   http://localhost/seatingreport4/index.php/help/ss.pdf   it displays  The page you requested was not found.

Comment: OK, let's do this: Find your index.php in your project folder, create a new folder EXACTLY where your index file is, let's say you name it "pdf", now paste your ss.pdf file in this new folder. Your include will work if you do include("pdf/ss.pdf");